# Apache service unavailable error code 503 , load balancing using tomcat as worker

Tags: apache, load-balancing, tomcat6, mod-jk, apache2.4

I am using windows 2008 R2 64 bit O.S, I downloaded httpd-2.4.10-win64-VC11 and tomcat-connectors-1.2.39-windows-x86_64-httpd-2.4.x and I created 3 tomcat workers and then I configured workers.properties and httpd.conf.

After complete setup when i tried using

http://localhost then

I got It works! message (looks everything is fine).

and then I have deployed my sample web application I tried to access the same application then using

http://localhost/SampleCluster

I am getting

503 service not available.

Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

I seen so many people are struck with this issue(I came to know when I searched for this issue)

What might be the problem ?

Please let me know.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally i am able resolve this issue guys,

the problem is for windows 2008 and windows 2012 servers mod_jk-1.2.39 or mod_jk-1.2.40 will not work, only Apache mod_jk-1.2.37 works on these platforms.

you have to choose mod_jk connector as per Apache httpd version, as mine was Apache 2.4 for I have downloaded mod_jk-1.2.37 version connector for  Apache 2.4.
Then finally it worked well.